# Calendar instance in android for AlarmManager

Tags: android, eclipse, calendar, alarmmanager

I am developing an app which displays notifications by using AlarmManager.
For that I'm taking the user input values for hour, minute and second.
Something like:

```
int hour = 4;
int min = 40;
int sec =36

Calendar Calendar_Object = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);
Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);
Calendar_Object.set(Calendar.SECOND, sec);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(MyView.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyView.this,0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, Calendar_Object.getTimeInMillis(), myIntent);
```

Notifications and the rest of the code work fine, but the problem is that instead of 4:40:36 the notifications get invoked on the current time(as soon as i run/debug the app).

I think there is some problem in Calender_Object part.
Looking for a solution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

#### Please note: Alarms will be executed immediately, if the notification time has elapsed already.

As a workaround you might want to consider a date part too. Or just a variable in memory which acts as a boolean if the time has elapsed or not.

From the [Docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

#### If the stated trigger time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately. If there is already an alarm for this Intent scheduled (with the equality of two intents being defined by filterEquals(Intent)), then it will be removed and replaced by this one.

Also please consider the API level 19 version of how AlarmManager works.